# downloading a h5 file in Google Colab

Tags: python, keras, python-requests, h5py

After a lot of search I still cannot find a way to retrieve a H5 file from remote, here is my code:

```
import requests
import io
import h5py

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aymeric75/IA/master/weights_bitcoin.h5'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('weights_btc.h5', 'wb').write(r.content)


if not h5py.is_hdf5('weights_btc.hdf5'):
    raise ValueError('Not an hdf5 file')
```

Thanks

p.s: I need this in Google Colab, because when saving a file different than a notebook, it is deleted when one quit the session.

Returns this error:

> ValueError: Not an hdf5 file

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
[4 Awesome Ways Of Loading ML Data In Google Colab](https://towardsdatascience.com/4-awesome-ways-of-loading-ml-data-in-google-colab-9a5264c61966)

Also, I would recommend connecting your google drive with collab if you want to use that model more often and not want to download it at each run. The following blog will help you.

[Simplest way to Open files from Google Drive in Google Colab](https://medium.com/ml-book/simplest-way-to-open-files-from-google-drive-in-google-colab-fae14810674)

Comment: Thanks but it then not possible for the file to be opened when sharing the link

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to save a dataset into an h5 file in Google collab. One way to accomplish this is

```
import io
import h5py

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aymeric75/IA/master/weights_bitcoin.h5'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

f= h5py.File('weights_btc.h5', 'w')
f.create_dataset(name ="Test", data = r.content)
f.close()

with open('weights_btc.h5', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Essentially, the h5 file on Github consists of dataset(s) or collections of dataset(s), attached to a group. I think it would much more pythonic to directly download the H5 file into an H5 object, kind of how we download a remote link into pandas. Not sure if there is a way to do so.

Comment: when I then use model.load_weights('weights_btc.h5'), I get the following error: OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found), meaning that it's not a h5 format